# Tricky Integration Problem

Tags: integration

I encountered the following integral in some of my research and I have not been successful at finding a way to solve it if it is even possible. The domain is $x \ge 0$ and over the reals.

\begin{equation}
\int \exp\left[\left(\frac{x}{x+2}\right)^3\right] dx
\end{equation}

I am fairly certain I have tried all standard techniques but to no success. The challenge seems to be with the fraction since a simpler form provides a more manageable solution, namely:

\begin{equation}
\int \exp\left[x^3\right] dx = \frac{1}{3}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3},-x^3\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: It is an indefinite integral.

Comment: The vast. vast majority of formulas built from simple functions do not have anti-derivatives that can be built from simple functions. Indeed $\Gamma$ itself doesn't really count as a simple function. But even allowing it and as many others as you can think of as being simple, my opening sentence is still true. There my be some acceptable expression for the anti-derivative, but I would waste much effort in hoping for it. It is easy to obtain Taylor series for the antiderivative about any point other than $-2$, with the distance to $-2$ as the radius of convergence.

Comment: @PaulSinclair - I suspected that in this case but I thought that just perhaps there was an interesting substitution or transformation.

Comment: It may be possible, but in terms of calculating values, finding a Taylor series and using it is generally easier and as fast or faster than calculating some really esoteric special function.